# Flutter Redux: How to wait for multiple dispatch results and dispatch an actions when all actions are completed

Tags: flutter, flutter-redux

When the app starts, I dispatch an action `FetchLocalDataRequestAction` and intercept this action in a middleware and dispatch multiple actions. I want to dispatch `FetchLocalDataCompleteAction` actions when all actions are completed. I was expecting that the dispatch function would return a `Future` which I can wait and when all the `Future`'s are completed I could have dispatched the complete action.
I'm using [redux_epics](https://pub.dev/packages/redux_epics) middleware for performing side effects using Streams

**Middleware**

```dart
fetchLocalData<State>(
  Store<State> store,
  action,
  NextDispatcher next
){
  if(action is FetchLocalDataRequestAction){
    final futureLanguage = store.dispatch(FetchPreferredLanguageRequestAction());
    print('futureLanguage : $futureLanguage '); // null
    store.dispatch(FetchLocalUserRequestAction());
    store.dispatch(FetchOnboardingStatusRequestAction());
  }

  next(action);
}
```

**Epics**

```dart
Stream fetchUserEpic(Stream actions, EpicStore<AppState> store) =>
    actions.whereType<FetchLocalUserRequestAction>()
    .debounceTime(Duration(seconds: 5))
    .switchMap((action) => _fetchUser());

  Stream _fetchUser() => 
    handleException<AuthResponse, FetchLocalUserResultAction, FetchLocalUserErrorAction>(
      api: () => _mergeUser(),
      onResult: (result) => FetchLocalUserResultAction(result),
      onError: (error) => FetchLocalUserErrorAction(error)
    );

  Future<AuthResponse> _mergeUser() async {
      final token = await SharedPreferenceService.getAccessToken();
      final user = await SharedPreferenceService.getUser();

      return AuthResponse(token: token, user: user);
  }

  Stream fetchPreferredLanguageEpic(Stream actions, EpicStore<AppState> store) =>
    actions.whereType<FetchPreferredLanguageRequestAction>()
    .switchMap((action) => _fetchPreferredLanguage());

  Stream _fetchPreferredLanguage() =>
    handleException<String, FetchPreferredLanguageResultAction, FetchPreferredLanguageErrorAction>(
      api: () => SharedPreferenceService.getLanguageCode(),
      onResult: (code) => FetchPreferredLanguageResultAction(code),
      onError: (error) => FetchPreferredLanguageErrorAction(error)
    );

   Stream fetchOnboardingStatusEpic(Stream actions, EpicStore<AppState> store) =>
    actions.whereType<FetchOnboardingStatusRequestAction>()
    .switchMap((action) => _fetchOnboardingStatus());

  Stream _fetchOnboardingStatus() =>
    handleException<OnboardingStatus, FetchOnboardingStatusResultAction, FetchOnboardingStatusErrorAction>(
      api: () => SharedPreferenceService.getOnboardingStatus(),
      onResult: (status) => FetchOnboardingStatusResultAction(status),
      onError: (error) => FetchOnboardingStatusErrorAction(error)
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a combination of [redux_thunk](https://pub.dev/packages/redux_thunk) package and [Future.wait](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.3/dart-async/Future/wait.html)

A `CallableThunkAction` will allow you to dispatch an action and await it.
Then, combined with `Future.wait`, you can make sure all actions complete:

```
class MyThunkAction1 implements CallableThunkAction<AppState> {
  @override call(Store<AppState> store) async => await asyncMethod();
}

class MyThunkAction1 implements CallableThunkAction<AppState> {
  @override call(Store<AppState> store) async => await otherAsyncMethod();
}


func fetchLocalStuff() async {  
  List<Future> list = await Future.wait(
    MyThunkAction1.call(),
    MyThunkAction2.call(), // these are futures
  );
  // do your thing
}
```